# ¿Alguien sabe donde esta el fallo?

Tags: xml

Siempre que creo un documento .dtd me sale un fallo en la primera linea y no entiendo porque

```
<!ELEMENT personas (persona, telefono)*>
<!ELEMENT persona (dni, nombre, apellidos, ciudad, fecha_n)>
<!ELEMENTdni (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT nombre [#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT apellidos (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ciudad (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT fecha_n (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT telefonos (dni_persona, telefono>
<!ELEMENT dni_persona (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT telefono (#PCDATA)>
```

El error es este

**FatalError at line 1, column 2: expected comment or CDATA section**

Comment: XML Copy Editor

Comment: Encierra el contenido completo del fichero entre una primera línea que diga `<!DOCTYPE PERSONAS [` y una última que diga `]>`

Comment: https://www.mclibre.org/consultar/xml/lecciones/xml-dtd.html#:~:text=Una%20DTD%20es%20un%20documento,ser%20hijos%20de%20cu%C3%A1les%2C%20etc.